# C#/XNA Randomize textures with no repeat

Tags: c#, random, xna

I'm trying to make a game where a grid of numbers randomize when you click on the one matching the number at the top.

I don't have the code for the mouse input yet but How would I randomize the grid of numbers so that there are no repeats and at least one of them matches with the top number?

Also, How would I make it so that the numbers only change when the mouse clicks on one of them so that they don't change every 1/60 second ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;  
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace numbergame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class NumberGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D hpBar, oneTex, twoTex, threeTex, fourTex, fiveTex, sixTex, sevenTex, eightTex, nineTex;
        Rectangle one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten;
        SpriteFont font;
        Vector2 score;
        float currentHealth = 100;
        Texture2D[] numGrid = new Texture2D[9];

    System.Random rng = new System.Random();

    private Texture2D GetRandomTexture()
    {
        return numGrid[rng.Next(0,9)];
    }

    public NumberGame()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        IsMouseVisible = true;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 600;
        Window.Title = "Number Game";
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        score = new Vector2(470,0);

        one = new Rectangle(170, 220, 60, 60);
        two = new Rectangle(270, 220, 60, 60);
        three = new Rectangle(370, 220, 60, 60);

        four = new Rectangle(170, 320, 60, 60);
        five = new Rectangle(270, 320, 60, 60);
        six = new Rectangle(370, 320, 60, 60);

        seven = new Rectangle(170, 420, 60, 60);
        eight = new Rectangle(270, 420, 60, 60);
        nine = new Rectangle(370, 420, 60, 60);

        ten = new Rectangle(270, 100, 60, 60);

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        hpBar = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar2");
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");

        numGrid[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("one");
        numGrid[1] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("two");
        numGrid[2] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("three");
        numGrid[3] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("four");
        numGrid[4] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("five");
        numGrid[5] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("six");
        numGrid[6] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("seven");
        numGrid[7] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("eight");
        numGrid[8] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("nine");

        oneTex = numGrid[0];
        twoTex = numGrid[1];
        threeTex = numGrid[2];
        fourTex = numGrid[3];
        fiveTex = numGrid[4];
        sixTex = numGrid[5];
        sevenTex = numGrid[6];
        eightTex = numGrid[7];
        nineTex = numGrid[8];

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        float deltaTime = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (currentHealth > 0)
        {
            currentHealth = Math.Max(0f, currentHealth - deltaTime * 25);
        }

        base.IsFixedTimeStep = true;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score:", score, Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.Draw(hpBar, new Rectangle(this.Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2 - hpBar.Width / 2, 30, hpBar.Width, 44), new Rectangle(0, 45, hpBar.Width, 44), Color.Gray);
        spriteBatch.Draw(hpBar, new Rectangle(this.Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2 - hpBar.Width / 2, 30, (int)(hpBar.Width * ((double)currentHealth/ 100)), 44), new Rectangle(0, 45, hpBar.Width, 44), Color.Red);
        spriteBatch.Draw(hpBar, new Rectangle(this.Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2 - hpBar.Width / 2, 30, hpBar.Width, 44), new Rectangle(0, 0, hpBar.Width, 44), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.Draw(oneTex, one, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), two, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), three, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), four, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), five, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), six, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), seven, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), eight, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), nine, Color.White);


        spriteBatch.Draw(GetRandomTexture(), ten, Color.LightSteelBlue);

        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCS7h.gif

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of *n* numbers, everytime you initialize your grid you randomly pick a number from it (using `System.Random`) for the top number, you remove it from the array and you also copy it the grid. You can do the same for the other numbers of the grid, removing a number everytime you add it in the grid, this will ensure that you won't have any repeated number.

For the other problem, if you want to make that the numbers only change when the mouse clicks on one of them, you simply need to update your structure when you detect a mouse click, instead of doing it every cycle.